# Mongoid: Parent of embedded document returning nil from field default lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have two Mongoid models defined as

```
class Owner
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :pets, class_name: 'Pet', inverse_of: :owner

  field :special_unit, type: String

end



class Pet
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps


  embedded_in :owner, inverse_of: :pets

  field :special_unit, default: lambda {
    if owner
      owner.special_unit
    else
      'default_value'
    end
  }
end
```

If I create a persisted `Owner` with `special_unit` field set.

```
owner = Owner.create(special_unit: 'foo')
owner.pets.create
owner.pets.first.special_unit
=> 'default_value'
```

The owners pet has `default_value` as the  value special unit. This is because `pet` is returning `nil` inside the lambda that the field default is calling. If I call `_parent` inside the lambda `nil` is also returned. Does anyone know why this is?

For further context I am able to call `#owner` and `#_parent` on an instance of `Pet` and return the expected owner. It's during the field default assignment that nil is returned.

I am using mongoid 6.4

Comment: Have you considered posting this as an issue on [mongoid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid)?

Comment: alas the repository does not allow the public to raise issues

Comment: It is very easy to create an account on their JIRA and drop an issue. I also noticed this on mongoid 7 while I did not have this behavior previously

Comment: I will add the issue @CyrilDuchon-Doris my company pays for Mongo support so I have access to their Jira

Comment: Hey @LewisJones I actually just fixed the bug I had, which was caused by a bad inverse declared in my model + changes to the way Mongoid 7 infers class_name from the namespace. So I actually did not confirm your bug on Mongoid 7, and actually I have never tried to set default values based from nested/parent associations using lambdas like you did, sorry for the previous comment.